# viewport not working to show desktop view on mobile- bootstrap design

Tags: html

I have a requirement from my client that I have to show desktop version on mobile. He told me that he wanted the website responsive so I used bootstrap and now he wants to show desktop view on mobile.

I went over many solutions on the internet, the only one that seems to be closely working for my case is setting the viewport tag.

Here's the code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Now the thing is it worked for the most part but still there are some areas where it is still following the responsive view. I also tried with `content="width=1200"`. It worked but there was a small horizontal scroll on the website or in some cases some part from the end is left blank!

Here's the live demo if anyone wants to see it:

```
http://nextcrawl.co/website/doubledouble/
```

Comment: hi ..have you tried to put in the header section this:                                   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: not working!!!! showing mobile view

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to have the proper meta view settings, what's left is to give your `.container` class a set width:

```
.container {
    width: 1024px;
}
```

And wrap your header nav and other elements into a `.container` div as well.

Comment: well i applied your logic with setting viewport and container to 1200 and guess what it worked just one small thing remains a horizontal scroll bar is there a way i can fix the desktop view on whole mobile screen without any horizontal scroll bar

Comment: @uneebmeer play around with adding `initial-scale=1` to your meta viewport settings in html as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: it shows the mobile version whereas i want the desktop version on mobile